# Pagination Not Working for Custom Taxonomy with Custom Query - 404 Error

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination

I am having trouble getting pagination working for custom taxonomy archive with the custom query. The pagination on the taxonomy archive ends up with a 404 page.

I have to run a query multiple times on many areas, so I have created a method for that.

## Query Method

```
/**
 * @param bool  $post_type
 * @param bool  $posts_per_page
 * @param bool  $paged
 * @param array $extra_args
 *
 * @return \WP_Query
 */
public function module_query( $post_type = FALSE, $posts_per_page = FALSE, $paged = FALSE, array $extra_args = [] ) {
    // basic arguments
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => $post_type ? $post_type : self::get_module_cpt(),
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page ? $posts_per_page : - 1,
        'orderby'        => 'title',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    ];

    // set paged
    if ( $paged ) {
        $args[ 'paged' ] = $paged;
    }

    $args = wp_parse_args( $extra_args, $args );

    // init meta query var
    $meta_query   = [];
    $meta_query[] = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_roles',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_users',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ],
    ];
    $meta_query[] = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_roles',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_users',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '=',
        ],
    ];

    // init permit roles var
    $permit_roles = [];
    $r            = 0;

    // loop through each roles and prepare array for meta query
    foreach ( $this->get_current_user_roles() as $current_user_role ) {
        $permit_roles[ $r ][ 'key' ]     = 'permit_roles';
        $permit_roles[ $r ][ 'value' ]   = sprintf( ':"%s";', $current_user_role );
        $permit_roles[ $r ][ 'compare' ] = 'LIKE';

        $r ++;
    }

    $meta_query[] = [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        $permit_roles,
        [
            'key'     => 'permit_users',
            'value'   => sprintf( ':"%s";', get_current_user_id() ),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
    ];

    // add meta query relation if more than one query
    if ( count( $meta_query ) > 1 ) {
        $meta_query[ 'relation' ] = 'OR';
    }

    // add meta query only for non admin users
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        $args[ 'meta_query' ] = $meta_query;
    }

    // return the query object
    return new WP_Query( $args );
}
```

## taxonomy.php Query

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$the_query = $cp->module_query(
    $cp::get_resource_cpt(), cp_get_addons_per_page(), $paged,
    [
        'orderby'   => 'publish_date',
        'tax_query' => [
            'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ $term->slug ],
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ],
    ]
);

...
// while loop
...

// pagination
$cp->bootstrap_pagination( $the_query );

// reset query
wp_reset_postdata();
```

## Pagination function

> The pagination is working fine on the Custom Post time page with a
> custom loop.

```
function bootstrap_pagination( \WP_Query $wp_query = NULL, $echo = TRUE ) {

    if ( NULL === $wp_query ) {
        global $wp_query;
    }

    $pages = paginate_links( [
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'type'         => 'array',
            'show_all'     => FALSE,
            'end_size'     => 3,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => TRUE,
            'prev_text'    => __( '« Prev' ),
            'next_text'    => __( 'Next »' ),
            'add_args'     => FALSE,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ]
    );

    if ( is_array( $pages ) ) {

        $pagination = '<div class="row"><div class="col mt-5"><div class="pagination d-flex justify-content-center"><ul class="pagination pagination-sm">';

        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            $pagination .= '<li class="page-item' . ( strpos( $page, 'current' ) !== FALSE ? ' active' : '' ) . '"> ' . str_replace( 'page-numbers', 'page-link', $page ) . '</li>';
        }

        $pagination .= '</ul></div></div></div><!-- end pagination -->';

        if ( $echo ) {
            echo $pagination;
        } else {
            return $pagination;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: If you must paginate a secondary loop/query in an archive page, then you can use `page_num`, `pg`, etc. query string in the pagination URL. But `paged` is reserved for the main query and it would result in the 404 error when the value is greater than the max number of pages for the main query.

Comment: @SallyCJ I understand a bit. but not sure how and where exactly to run the second loop and what I should pass?

Comment: I hope the answer helps? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In short, your code is fine, but the custom query's pagination and the one for the main query, they can't be using the same `paged` URL query string* (which WordPress reads the value from for the `paged` query arg used in a `WP_Query` request).

### Why the error 404?

So for examples, paginated/paged category requests can have one of these URLs:

- Full pretty URL:
  `https://example.com/category/uncategorized/page/2/`
- Semi-pretty URL which redirects to the above URL:
  `https://example.com/category/uncategorized/?paged=2`
- "Ugly URL" (e.g. when permalinks are not enabled)
  `https://example.com/?cat=1&paged=2`

And as you can see, the URLs are using the query string `paged` which you can get the value using `get_query_var( 'paged' )`. (Note that in the first URL, the `page/2` is equivalent to `paged=2`)

And because a category/taxonomy archive is a **non**-singular request (just like search results pages), the `paged` value will be used in the main query's request, i.e. the SQL command for querying the requested archive, unless of course if pagination is *not* enabled for the main query.

Therefore, the `paged` value needs to be valid, i.e. it must not exceed the *max number of* pages for that specific request (the main query). And if the max is exceeded, then you'd get a `404` error because there were no more posts found via the main query. Just like a book with 10 pages (including covers); there's logically no page #11, right?

So because your custom query is being paginated using the `paged` query string, then if you get the error 404, it's likely because the custom query had more pages than the main query.

Sample scenario demonstrating the above:

- On a category archive page (e.g. at `example.com/category/uncategorized`), there were 3 pages shown in the pagination. And that's for the main query which WordPress runs first on page load.
- Then in the category template, you run a custom query for, maybe a custom post type.
- Then you added a pagination for the custom query and there were 5 pages shown in that pagination.
- So if both the paginations are using the same `paged` query string, then for example, going to page #4 will cause a `404` error because the main query (for the category) had only at most 3 pages of results.

### How to fix the error

(**Note:** These are listed in *no specific order*.)

- As I said in the comments, you can use a custom URL query string like `page_num`, `pg`, etc. along with `paged`.

  So the `paged` will always be just for the main query, while `page_num` or `pg` will be used with your custom query.
- Use AJAX instead to paginate the custom query, but AJAX is not in scope of this answer. (Or that it's up to you to look for a solution and implement it.)
- Use a static Page (post of the `page` type), e.g. at `example.com/my-tax-archive`, and run your custom queries in the Page Template.

  For singular requests, WordPress doesn't use the `paged` in the request SQL, so the `paged` value can be any number (2, 20, 200, 2000, etc.).

### But there's a trick to make `paged` works for both the main query and custom queries.. on archive pages.

1. Add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

   ```php
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
       if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ||
           ! is_tax( 'your_tax' ) ) {
           return;
       }

       if ( ! empty( $_GET['pgs'] ) &&
           ( $paged = max( 1, $query->get( 'paged' ) ) ) &&
           // Runs only if the current page number exceeds the main query's max pages.
           $paged > $_GET['pgs']
       ) {
           $query->set( 'pg', $paged );          // for the custom query's pagination
           $query->set( 'paged', $_GET['pgs'] ); // for the main query's pagination

           // Prevent WordPress from redirecting to page/<max pages>.
           remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
       } else {
           $query->set( 'pg', $query->get( 'paged' ) );
       }
   } );
   ```
2. Then in the `bootstrap_pagination()` function, apply the four (`[1]` to `[4]`) changes below:

   ```php
   // [1] Add the $use_alt
   function bootstrap_pagination( \WP_Query $wp_query = NULL, $echo = TRUE, $use_alt = null ) {

       ...

       // [2] Add these:
       $add_args = [];
       if ( $use_alt ) {
           $add_args['pgs'] = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages;
       }

       $pages = paginate_links( [
               ...
               // [3] Use this instead.
               'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( $use_alt ? 'pg' : 'paged' ) ),
               ...
               // [4] Use the $add_args
               'add_args'     => $add_args,
               ...
           ]
       );

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Then in the archive/`taxonomy.php` template:

   ```php
   // Define the $paged like so:
   $paged = max( 1, get_query_var( 'pg' ) );

   // ... your code here.

   // Then call bootstrap_pagination() like so:
   bootstrap_pagination( $the_query, true, true );
   ```

Tried & tested working, but obviously as you can see above, once the max num pages for the main query has been reached, the next pages will set the `paged` to that max num pages value. So it's up to you how to not make that "look bad/weird/whatever" and to handle things like performance (if your custom query had 20 extra pages than the main query, then one would see the main query's last page 20 times.. if they viewed them all).

Comment: Thank you so much @SallyCJ. I appreciate your detailed explanation. However, I am still unable to resolve the issue. The query I am using, it's a `method` I have posted in the question. I can't see anything wrong but if you can find anything please let me know.

Comment: Is it just page #2 and above that gives you the error 404? And although I'm not positive about this, perhaps flushing the rewrite rule helps? (Just visit the permalink settings page) But if not, can you add your taxonomy and post type registration code?

Comment: Hi, please ignore my previous comment and see the revised answer. :)

Comment: I truly appreciate your effort and dedication to helping me. I have tried this but it is not working and end up with 404. I have no idea what is wrong here. I have to flush the permalink as well. It is generating a URL like this. `http://site.dev/taxonomy/term/page/2/?pgs=1`

Comment: Page #1 loads correctly, right? Have you tried deactivating all plugins? How about clearing cache on your site and in the browser? But if none of that helps, then I guess you should install Query Monitor (QM), activate it and on the taxonomy page, inspect the QM's results.

Comment: Let me try with all of them you said. I have almost done the project but stuck just on it.

Comment: Nothing changes. I made a video https://www.loom.com/share/9c76281f81af4a6b997fdf10e24dba94 It may help to see what is exactly happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110299/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-pixelngrain).

Comment: It was my stupid mistake. I overlooked `is_tax()` argument. I have many taxonomies that run the same loop so instead of passing `taxonomy` in `is_tax()` I leave it blank so that will apply to all taxonomies. Here is the video https://www.loom.com/share/15214f95ac794fda9638345f46ecb0ba Millions thanks agin.

Answer (score 1):

If you facing the same issue so please go to the reading option page in settings and check how many numbers were set in the "Blog pages show at most" field value. if "Blog pages show at most" values are set greater than compared to your custom archive page or default page query string per page post parameter so you need to change the backend "Blog pages show at most" field value to match custom query per page post value.

For example :
"Blog pages show at most" field value is 12 and my custom query is

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'include_children' => true,
            'terms' => array(get_queried_object_id())
        )
    ),
    'paged' => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

As an above query, you see posts_per_page parameter value is 10 but still, we have set 12 in backend so it will cause an issue in pagination page because it will consider per page 12 posts so please change 12 to 10 and pagination will work properly, In my case, it works.